# Hibernate One to Many relationship with attributes on the relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, entity-relationship

Basic Hibernate question.

I have a class called `Song` and a class called `Artwork`, both exist independently. Then an instance of `Song` can contain multiple `Artwork`s and when they do there are attribute particular to that relationship so I have created another class called `CoverArt` that links between the two. I'm using annotations for the hibernate stuff and having problems.

If I annotate all three classes as `@Entity` when I build the database I get the error >'org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Artwork, at table: CoverArt, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(artwork)]'

If I change `CoverArt` to `@Embeddable`, as it only exists in the context of a `Song` I get the error

> 'org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: Declaring class is not found in the inheritance state hierarchy: com.jthink.songlayer.CoverArt'

I can't work out what these messages are saying, what I have wrong. Here is the relevant code from the three classes

`Song`:

```
@Entity
public class Song
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer recNo;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @IndexColumn(name = "POSITION")
    private List<CoverArt> coverArt; 

.....
```

`CoverArt`:

```
@Embeddable
public class CoverArt
{
    private String  imageType;
    private String  description;
    private Artwork artwork;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    public CoverArt()
    {

    }

    public String getImageType()
    {
        return imageType;
    }

    public void setImageType(String imageType)
    {
        this.imageType = imageType;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Artwork getArtwork()
    {
        return artwork;
    }

    public void setArtwork(Artwork artwork)
    {
        this.artwork = artwork;
    }
}
```

`Artwork`:

```
@Entity
public class Artwork
{

    public Artwork()
    {

    }

    public Artwork(byte[] imageData)
    {
        this.imageData=imageData;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;


    @Lob
    private byte[]  imageData;
    private String  mimeType;
    private int     width;
    private int     height;

    public byte[] getImageData()
    {
        return imageData;
    }

    public void setImageData(byte[] imageData)
    {
        this.imageData = imageData;
    }

    public String getMimeType()
    {
        return mimeType;
    }

    public void setMimeType(String mimeType)
    {
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
    }

    public int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width)
    {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height)
    {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CoverArt` class should be an entity.

The `Song` has a list of `CoverArt` instances, you should thus have

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(...)
private List<CoverArt> coverArts; // note the final s, since it's plural
```

Each `CoverArt` links to an `Artwork`, so you should also have an association. It's not clear if it's a ManyToOne or a OneToOne, tough. I'll suppose it's a OneToOne:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(...)
private Artwork artwork;
```

It's pretty simple. Each time an entity has a reference to another entity, or a collection of another entity instances, you have an assosiation. And an association can be a OneToMany, OneToOne, ManyToOne or ManyToMany. You have to tell Hibernate which one it is. If you don't tell it, it assumes it's a simple Column which is wrong.

Comment: Thankyou adding OneToMany in Song and OneToOne in Artwork has done the trick, I didn't need to use JoinColumn. But why does CoverArt have to be an entiy it only exists in the context of the Song, is it because it is linking to an entity ?

Comment: You could make it an embedded object, but it would only make it harder, and you wouldn't be able to query them as you can with entities. I usually prefer using an entity when somthing must be mapped to its own table.

Comment: and to get my code that uses this to work I needed to do @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) hope that is not hiding a problem in my code.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation to understand what this means and what the implications are, rather than adding annotations and attributes without understanding them, until it happens to work?

Comment: I have been reading http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Persistence-Hibernate-Christian-Bauer/dp/1932394885/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1328645619&sr=8-1 but finding it extremely difficult to understand so that why I find myself having to try things out

Answer (score 0):

First of all You should tell us how do You want all that to look like in database.
I assume You want something like that:

table 'songs'
table 'artworks'
table 'cover_arts' with fkeys: song_id and artwork_id

So a Song "has many" CoverArts and each CoverArt "has one" Artwork.

If this is correct, then:

- Annotate CoverArt with @Entity instead of @Embeddable
- inside CoverArt class annotate field 'artwork' with @ManyToOne
- replace  @ElementCollection on field 'coverArt' inside Song class with @OneToMany. It would be nice to rename field 'coverArt' to 'coverArts' as it is a collection, not a single instance.

Comment: Thankyou sounds correct like other poster, although interesting you say to use ManyToOne instead of OneToOne